# multiple arrays data posting and mysql insert using foreach php

Tags: php

i have form as below with same name text field columns, i want to insert multiple arrays data to mysql using this below form. pls tell me how to do this using foreach in php mysql

First Column

```
<input  name="date[]" type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="local[]" />
<input type="text" name="desc[]" />
<input type="text" name="ta[]" />
<input type="text" name="car[]" />
```

Second Column

```
<input  name="date[]" type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="local[]" />
<input type="text" name="desc[]" />
<input type="text" name="ta[]" />
<input type="text" name="car[]" />
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would rename your form fields to make this easier:

```
<?php
$number_of_columns = 2;
for($i=0;$i<$number_of_columns;$i++) :?>
    <input  name="col[<?=$i?>][date]" type="text" class="datepicker">
    <input type="text" name="col[<?=$i?>][local]" />
    <input type="text" name="col[<?=$i?>][desc]" />
    <input type="text" name="col[<?=$i?>][ta]" />
    <input type="text" name="col[<?=$i?>][car]" />
<?php endfor;?>
```

And then once you get the data, you can just loop through the `$_POST['col']` array and insert each one individually into the database. I'm assuming here that you've already connected to your database and are using the mysql library.

```
$cols = $_POST['col'];
$table = 'table_name';
foreach($cols as $col) {
    $local = mysql_real_escape_string($col['local']);
    $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($col['desc']);
    $ta = mysql_real_escape_string($col['ta']);
    $car = mysql_real_escape_string($col['car']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`local`, `desc`, `ta`, `car`) VALUES('{$local}', '{$desc}', '{$ta}', '{$car}')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thank You jraede it is working great. i am searching for two days for this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
extract($_POST);
$n = count($date);
for ($i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, `c5`) VALUES (\'' . $date[$i] . '\', \'' . $local[$i] . '\', \'' . $desc[$i] . '\', \'' . $ta[$i] . '\', \'' . $car[$i] . '\')';
    // Here you must execute your query
}
```

Comment: Thank You Michael It is Working fine.

Comment: Hai Michael can help me. Code working but inserting some blank rows in mysql table, because if we didn't type values in some rows in form.